# 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'c.replace(bo,"-$1")')

Tags: jquery

I need to use jQuery effects for showing or hiding a div. However I get an error in console after any of the following methods gets executed.

The animation completes for the first time, but after the animation completes the error is shown in Safari console and I am not able to apply any other jquery method on the same div again.

I am sure this is due to some other code is messing up in the application as the following code works fine in jsfiddle.

```
$('#testDiv').slideDown() 
$('#testDiv').slideUp() 
$('#testDiv').show('slow') 
$('#testDiv').hide('slow') 
$('#testDiv').toggle('slow')
```

error

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'c.replace(bo,"-$1")')
```

element

```
<div id='testDiv'>text</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a full sample showing this error? Maybe jsfiddle?

Comment: your methods are fine. It's something else you need to fix. Console is your friend.

Comment: this works fine when checking with a test html page or in jsfiddle. the error occurs only in my project which i have joined recently. The jquery library file is  unaltered. but am not sure why this error occurs in the application.

Comment: That error is probably not related to the code above at all, as it looks just fine, and shouldn't cause any errors.

Comment: the console doesn't show any error when using $('#testDiv').show() or $('#testDiv').hide() which have no animation effects. The error only occurs in the above mentioned function with animation effects.

Comment: I can foresee three circumstances that could bring this error about. #1) That is not the actual selector, and, whatever selector you're using is bad. #2) More than 1 version of jQuery is loaded on the page, likely a Wordpress site. #3) You're not using version 1.43 + of jQuery, which allowed for the use of `strings` as a parameter of the show/hide functions. Not 100%, but maybe it'll help you.

Comment: we also use the Zapatec framework(http://sourceforge.net/projects/zapatec/) in the same application. may be that  might have messed up with the jQuery effects?

Comment: can you setup a jsfiddle to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Could you please provide a list and ordering of the javascript files your application is loading?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/ZapatecGridUtil.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="zapatec/utils/zapatec.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zapatec/utils/utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zapatec/zpgrid/src/zpgrid.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zapatec/zpgrid/src/zpgrid-xml.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zapatec/zptabs/src/zptabs.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the Json library was messing up with the jQuery 1.6.4

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Replaced the toJSONString() with JSON.strigify() and this error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Given these statements (**all** quoted):

- `the console doesn't show any error when using $('#testDiv').show() or $('#testDiv').hide()`
- `this works fine when checking with a test html page or in jsfiddle.`
- `the error occurs only in my project`
- `The jquery library file is unaltered`

Here is what **I** think:

jQuery [show('slow')](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide('slow')](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) were introduced in [jQuery-1.0](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.0/).

> The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively.

In javascript anything (**almost**) can be a variable name:

[image]

In many cases many libraries uses the `$` symbol, it just got extra popular with the release of jQuery, so some libraries could use the same `$`.

In jQuery the `$` sign is a shorthand for `jQuery`.

**My** advice:

Ensure jQuery is the **last** js file to be loaded, **just to check** if another javascript file is overriding some of the functionality of jQuery. If jQuery now works it was being overriden by another javascript file.

Then do this as a **definitive** solution:

Do `$.noConflict();` Which will free the `$` for other libraries which uses it and start using `jQuery` instead of `$`.

[This fiddle](http://jsbin.com/abnnn/1) works with `jquery-1.0.1` (Couldn't find 1.0), here is the javascript code:

```
$(function() {
    $('button#hideSlow').click(function() { $('p#hello').hide('slow'); });
    $('button#showSlow').click(function() { $('p#hello').show('slow'); });
});
```

Resources:

- [jQuery API Documentation: jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).
- [Valid JavaScript variable names](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers).
- [Here is a Gist with the same code as in the fiddle](https://gist.github.com/estebanmurchio/2c1679271a87ae04659b).

Comment: I would've posted this as a comment, but comments can't be longer than 600 characters, If this answer does not apply I will delete it.